# set time interval for javascript function in "microseconds"

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I wish to animate an element in such a way that it move only 1px downwards every 1 microsecond, that is 0.001 milliseconds.

```
var microsec = 0.001

$("div").animate({top: "+=1px"},microsec);
```

Please advice.

Comment: Remember that at 60fps, every frame is displayed on the screen for ~16.7 milliseconds before the screen re-draws. So if you move one pixel every microsecond, then the only thing the user will see is your object jumping 16667 pixels next time the screen redraws, ~16.7 milliseconds later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**4 ms is the minimum timeout in standard HTML5 according to the spec**

See this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting

You may think you can assign any amount of duration in millisecond which is as small as you want in JavaScript, however, it is limited by the HTML5 spec that the **minimum delay (DOM_MIN_TIMEOUT_VALUE) implemented in modern browsers are set to 4 ms**. Even more, Firefox implements it 5 ms.

jQuery is implemented on top of JavaScript and therefore complies this rule. So, it's not possible to achieve "micro or nano seconds of delay" in JavaScript at all.

Comment: More importantly, it is not needed to achieve what the poster wants ("bumpiness free" motion). While what you are saying is true, I think is more important to guide the user to a more appropriate direction.

Comment: The HTML5 spec is as much about what browsers actually do as it is about what they should do (without pointing out the difference). In this case, it's probably not a limitation imposed by the spec, but rather documentation of what browsers actually do.

Comment: Yes, much likely bumpiness-free motion cannot be achieved with reducing the interval and may need additional advice apart from current answers in this thread. However, the primary question is straightforward about "how to achieve microsecond animation in JS" which technically can't be done due to the fact that there is no smaller timeout delay than 4 ms.

Answer (score 4):

Javascript does not offer microseconds accuracy. However, it is a weird accuracy to think about when doing regular things, you should be more than fine with milliseconds.

Comment: Nothing is weird. I need to create a motion effect on mousemove. The problem is that as the function is triggered on mousemove, the effect should be executed fast enough without any "bumpy" motion effect. Anyway, believe me because i have been working on this project for weeks now. I'm sure of what i need.

Comment: Too bad what you need isn't possible, no matter how sure you are!

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Now I know one approach that won't work. Let me try another

Comment: My point is that you don't need to go for microseconds to avoid bumpiness. Think about the TV or the movies, with only 30 frames per second you achieve continuity. In computers is more about CPU scheduling and video hertz refresh rate than time scales. Google some of that concepts if you can.

Comment: @jotadepicas—but those technologies achieve smooth motion through antialiasing, which is not available through simple movement by coordinates but might be implemented through styles.